# How to get data from db to layout in Laravel 8.*

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

So I know how to retrieve data to views(using classes in controller)
but how can I return some data to layout which doesnt(or rather i dont know where they are) have its classes where i could get code to do so.

here is my form in which i would like to put cities name.

I always do it by giving to my frontend controller data from db using

```php
$events = DB::select('select * from events');

return view('frontend/index', ['event' => $events]);
```

---

Edit

How to pass `$city->id` from loop to action?

My `app.blade` form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{!! route('cityView', ['id' => $city->id]) !!}" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="city_id" class="form-control">
            <option>xd</option>
            @foreach(\App\Models\City::all() as $city)
                <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button></a>
</form>
```

But how can I do it for a layout?

Would making a layout controller help with it? Or maybe make another class inside existing controller and return view of layout view?

Second solution would be adding this form to every single view since there will be only 3 of them but i prefer solution with `app.blade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call data directly from layout something like this:

```html
<form method="POST" action="#" class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="room_size" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            @foreach(\App\Models\City::all() as $city)
                <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Every day we learn something new, thank you kindy Sir. I've got a question tho, is it save to use?

Comment: Well I can't answer this correctly if it is safe to use. I have seen this in some of the production projects and been using it myself and didn't experience any security problems yet. But if you don't like this approach you can also make this form as component and use ```php artisan make:component Form``` and it creates class for this component where you can pass data. You can find more information here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components

Comment: Thank you.

I fell on another problem there, it does pass data to url but then i cant pass its value to {id} inside action because $city is declared after this. can i move action somewere behind loop so i can actually use it? My route: action="{!! route('cityView', ['id' => $city_id]) !!}"

I edited main question so its a bit clearer.

Comment: In that way you need to move form inside ```@foreach``` but this will multiple your form.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to get selected value into route. Dont need post method there probably tho

Comment: In your way I would take that selected value inside controller from request data you send and I suppose it is update method for you that you are working with. And use that selected value where I need. Also change route name to not use any parameters.

Comment: Problem is that this is layout view and it doesnt have any controller. Guess i will just past this to normal view and do it with controller, thank you for your tips!